# Compare two somewhat large objects for equality

Tags: c++

I have to compare two larger objects for equality.

Properties of the objects:

1. Contain all their members by value (so no pointers to follow).
2. They also contain some `stl::array`.
3. They contain some other objects for which 1 and 2 hold.
4. Size is up to several kB.
5. Some of the `members` will more likely differ than others, therefore lead to a quicker break of the comparison operation if compared first.
6. The objects do not change. Basically, the algorithm is just to count how many objects are the same. Each object is only compared once against several "master" objects.

What is the best way to compare these objects? I see three options:

1. Just use plain, non-overloaded `operator==`.
2. Overload `==` and perform a member-by-member comparison, beginning with members likely to differ.
3. Overload `==` and view the object as a plain byte field and compare word by word.

**Some thoughts:**
Option 1 seems good because it means the least amount of work (and opportunities to introduce errors).
Option 2 seems good, because I can exploit the heuristic about which elements differ most likely. But maybe it's still slower because built-in `==`of option 1 is ridiculously fast.
Option 3 seems to be most "low-level" optimized, but that's what the compiler probably also does for option 1.

So the **questions** are:

- Is there a well-known best way to solve the task?
- Is one of the options an absolute no-go?
- Do I have to consider something else?

Comment: Comparing hashes is an option as well

Comment: One optimization I like to do when you have a bunch of arrays, compare the lengths of all the corresponding array members of your two objects, and then if all the corresponding lengths match, THEN think about looking at comparing the members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good question.

If you have some heuristic about which members are likely to differ - use it. So that overloading `operator ==` and checking suspected members first seems to be a good idea.

About byte-wise comparison (aka `memcmp` and friends) - may be problematic due to struct member alignment. I.e. the compiler sometimes puts "empty spaces" in your struct layout, so that each member will have required alignment. Those are not initialized and usually contain garbage.

This may be solved by explicit zero-initializing of your whole object. But, I don't see any advantage of `memcmp` vs automatic `operator ==`, which is a members-wise comparison. It probably may save some code size (a single call to `memcpy` vs explicit reads and comparisons), however from the performance perspective this seems to be pretty much the same.

Comment: What is an "automatic operator ==" ?

Answer (score 4):

Default == is fast for small objects, but if you have big data members to compare, try to find some optimizations thinking about the specific data stored and the way they are update, redefining an overloaded == comparison operator more "smarter" than the default one.

As many already said, option 3 is wrong, due to the fact that fields generally are padded to respect the data-alignment, and for optimization reason the bytes added are not initialized to 0 (maybe this is done in the DEBUG version).

I can suggest you to explore the option to divide the check in two stages:

- first stage, create some sort of small & fast member that "compress" the status of the instance (think like an hash); this field could be updated every time some big field changes, for example the elements of the stl-array. Than check frequently changed fields and this "compress" status first to make a conservative comparison (for example, the sum of all int in the array, or maybe the xor)
- second stage, use an in-deep test for every members. This is the slowest but complete check, but likely will be activated only sometimes

Answer (score 0):

In case the objects are not trivial keep the [following note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) about the `memcmp` in mind:

*This function reads object representations, not the object values, and is typically meaningful for **only trivially-copyable objects that have no padding.***

-> So, I would go for overloading the == of the objects and do direct members comperison. I would also not suggest using hash comparison since [calculating hashs of e.g. large strings is a costly operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887288/11671205).